# Check for a Valid URL string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, uri

I have an MVC application and I am going through a strange situation right now.

I am allowing users to stare and Display website URL's. I am using the following method to check whether the following URL is correct or not:

```
if(Uri.TryCreate(urlString, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
{
// Do something
}
else
{
// Invalid Url
}
```

This method is not working because when I try URL starting with "www" or directly with the domain name then it does'not work.

I want the first section of If statement to be bullet proof.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: `allowing users to stare`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try to create a new URI in a try-catch block.

Something like:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

If you get to the `catch` then it's a wrong URL.